# rancher reverse proxy outside cluster

Tags: rancher

Hello I have on the same machine (myserver.com) rancher server and rancher agent.

Rancher is started with -p 8080:80 -p 8443:443 and agent is using 80 and 443.

I would like to access the rancher app directly on 443 (not on 8443), maybe using https://rancher.myserver.com that goes to https://myserver.com:8443 but I did not succeed doing this...

I have tried to add an ingress entry with rancher.myserver.com as the hostname to use and a service with external hostname target myserver.com and target port 8443.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Rancher should listen on port 80 and 443.

Rancher doc is well describing the install process on a single node :

[Rancher single node install](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node/)

In your case :

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped \
  -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  rancher/rancher:latest
```

Then create a dns record pointing to that ip.

Comment: this does not work for me.... I am in this use case: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node/#running-rancher-rancher-and-rancher-rancher-agent-on-the-same-node

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to create a single node RKE cluster and deploy Rancher using the helm chart. By doing this you can use the built-in nginx-ingress which listens on port 80 and 443.

You can also deploy your applications on the local cluster. Then use host-based routing in nginx-ingress to route traffic to your applications.